# Group by in pivot table in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

How can I group by this pivot table

```
select * 
from 
    (SELECT     
        ProductionID,ProductionDetailID,                
        [DeviceID],[DeviceSpeed],[LattNO] 
     from 
        (SELECT      
            * 
         from view_3 
         where ProductionID = 6) x pivot 
        (
            max(Value)FOR PropertyName  in ([DeviceID],[DeviceSpeed],[LattNO])
        )  AS pvt ) as  pp
```

Result:

```
ProductionID  ProductionDetailID  DeviceID  DeviceSpeed  LattNO
6                     2             5           NULL      NULL
6                     2             NULL          8       NULL
6                     2             NULL         NULL      6
6                     3             1            NULL     NULL
6                     3             NULL          2       NULL
```

and how can I get this result:

```
  ProductionID  ProductionDetailID  DeviceID  DeviceSpeed  LattNO
      6            2                  5          8          6
      6            3                  1          2          NULL
```

Comment: Stop using `SELECT *` and only use the columns you actually need to return in the subquery.   You are obviously including an additional column that is causing the grouping to fail, but without seeing your table definitions, we'd be guessing as to what column is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT
ProductionID,ProductionDetailID, Sum(Cast(isnull([DeviceID],0) as Int)) [DeviceID],Sum(Cast(isnull([DeviceSpeed],0) as Int)) [DeviceSpeed],Case Sum(Cast(isnull([LattNO],0) as Int)) When 0 then Null else  Sum(Cast(isnull([LattNO],0) as Int))  End  [LattNO] from 
            (
               SELECT 
               * FROM dbo.View_3
           )
            x pivot 
            (
                max(Value)FOR PropertyName  in ([DeviceID],[DeviceSpeed],[LattNO])
            )  AS pvt 
Group by ProductionID , ProductionDetailID

Comment: Go Haleshoo Bebar www.nicelabel.ir